# change connection string automatically on publish azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service project. I have two web projects and 4 class libraries.
I want to, on azure publish, change connection string automatically for web roles and also for the class libraries.
I have two deployment slots: one for staging and other for production. I want to select automatically connectionstrings for staging when it's running on staging and production when running on production.
I found a lot of solutions on the net but it doesn't show how to change connection string for projects other than web roles (class libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using Web Apps, since you mention Deployment Slots. Each slot has their own Application Settings sections, all you need to do is go to the Slot and set the Connection String you want to use and check the "Slot Setting" mark.

[image]

This will make sure that, even if you Swap, that setting (the Connection String) remains [fixed to that Slot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/#configuration-for-deployment-slots).

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you should create 2 set of configuration files (Web.config). One for Staging and other for production. While publishing your web project, choose the profile in publish dialog box accordingly(For Staging / Production). Visual studio will take of your configuration to be deployed in server.

This link will be helpful for you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w(v=vs.110).aspx